# Python, Printing 15 instead of 0.15

Tags: python

Is there a way to print out 15 instead of 0.15? For example to have this outcome

tipCalculator(60.00,0.15) <----- the input is 0.15 but writes 15% when you print it.

Ex. A 15% tip on a bill of $60.00 will come to $69.00 total.

Comment: `print("15")` should do the trick.

Comment: very very simple math. as @interjay said. Spend a little more time thinking about a problem before asking questions :)

Answer (score 2):

Use Python's [formatting language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
>>> '{:.2%}'.format(.15)
'15.00%'
>>> '{:.0%}'.format(.15)
'15%'
>>> 'Bill: ${:.2f}, tip: {:.2%}, Total ${:.2f}'.format(bill, tip, bill+bill*tip) 
'Bill: $60.00, tip: 15.00%, Total $69.00'
```